# Can`t reinstall mysql on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, mysql

Every time I try to install MySQL I get

```
Setup package mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Setup package mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
150415 15:35:15 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
150415 15:35:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150415 15:35:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150415 15:35:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150415 15:35:16 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 1595675
150415 15:35:16 [ERROR] Aborting

150415 15:35:16  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150415 15:35:17  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
150415 15:35:17 [Note] 
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while configure mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет mysql-client (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                          dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет mysql-server:
 mysql-server зависит от mysql-server-5.5, однако:
  Пакет mysql-server-5.5 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-16) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

All answers that I find in the net advice to do:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

But I can`t because I use KUbuntu, so purge mysql-common will delete most of packages :(

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`